# mailing in asp.net

Tags: email

I wanna send an E-mail from my asp.net form...
My code is......

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
        m.From = new MailAddress("rkrishnan111@yahoo.co.in", "RK");
        m.To.Add(new MailAddress("rkrishnan111@yahoo.co.in", "KRISHNAN"));
        m.Subject = "Hello";
        m.Body = "hi";
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
        client.Send(m);
```

But i got the following error message,

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: authentication required - for help go to http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/mail/pop/pop-11.html

What should i do...?

Answer (score 0):

It was there in the link itself.

**Subscription to Yahoo! Mail Plus Service**: You must subscribe to the Yahoo! Mail Plus service for POP access through your email client.

**POP Access Option**: Click Options in the upper-right corner of your Mail page and select Mail Options. From the list on the left, click POP & Forwarding, then Set up or edit POP & Forwarding. Now: is there a dot in the circle beside "Web & POP Access"? If so, great! If not, that means there's a dot in the circle beside "Forwarding." Your account's NOT POP-enabled whenever you select the "Forwarding" option, because these two separate features can't be used at the same time. If you make a change here, make sure to click Save when you're done.

**Client Settings**: Is there a problem with your email client settings? Please make sure that you've configured your email client with these settings:

```
* Incoming Mail (POP3) Server: plus.pop.mail.yahoo.com (Use SSL, port: 995)
* Outgoing (SMTP) Server: plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com (Use SSL, port: 465, 
  use authentication)
* Account Name/Login Name: your Yahoo! ID (your email address without the 
  "@yahoo.com")
* Email Address: your Yahoo! Mail address (e.g., user@yahoo.com)
```

**Set Up** Have you selected an incompatible log-in method or server type when you set up your email client? To check your settings, please follow the steps below for your email client.

Comment: My bet's that if they missed it the first time, and they didn't get it now, it needs to be said ;)